# CUDA path in Sagemaker instances to solve NameError: name '_C' is not defined with GroundingDINO

Tags: python, machine-learning, cuda, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to install and use [grounding dino](https://github.com/IDEA-Research/GroundingDINO) in a Sagemaker instance (with GPU) but i got the error:

```
NameError: name '_C' is not defined
```

I found out the reason is because the variable CUDA_HOME is not configured so to solve it I need to set the variable, but after searching for answers(I already checked the common path /usr/local/cuda) I cannot find the path where cuda is installed in sagemaker instances.

Where is cuda installed in sagemaker instances so I can set CUDA_HOME?

Answer (score -1):

the CUDA_HOME is usually set the cuda installed path, for example, `/usr/local/cuda` or `/usr/local/cuda-12.2` etc. Maybe, you can have a try.